# Eclipse luna Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/content.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-luna

I try all solution on the internet but no result, it's seems that my eclipse won't connect to internet, every time i try to install for example new softwares i have error message:

Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/content.xml.
Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/content.xml.
Address family not supported by protocol family: connect

I spend hours on this problem :(

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem for me was that on apache-maven-3.2.5\conf\settings.xml     i have a proxy, so i delete it and every thing works fine

Answer (score 2):

Starting Eclipse with -vmargs -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true works for me